# Can't find any registered devices yet

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push

I have an issue with the Quick Start Guide on Parse ! I download the source code, I uncommented the line in order to insert my keys :

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"**********"
          clientKey:@"********"];
```

Don't know if the id and the key are private.

So, when I click on the Test button I got this message :

> Can't find any registered devices yet...

I run my app on my iphone, I have a dev account, it's all set, SSL certificate ... So I don't know what to do

Thanks for your help !

Comment: have you created any user against your application ?

Comment: @adnan : Sorry I don't understand your question ? :/

Comment: login in parse.com . Create some user

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa first you create your app in parse.com (create first account ) and get the credential for your app. https://www.parse.com/#signup .Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, Created my app on Parse.com, uploaded my .P12 file for push notification , what should I do after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login To Parse ...

Go to View Dashboard.. you will see all apps created..(probably only one for you) Click the gear icon in the right corner of your app box.

On the next screen select the second option in the right-hand menu list (Application Keyes)

Comment: Yeah I know I have the App Id and the Client ID, but still it doesn't work with these IDs..

Comment: On my screen "You're all set with Parse !" , but then on the website I can't send any push notifications ..

Comment: I have seen various idiot proof guides on youtube. You should check it out:    [link]https://www.google.co.za/search?q=youtube+parse+push+notifications&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Wxf-U5-HPKjd8gfYioHwAg

Comment: i've been having this same problem with the applicationID and ClientID ... don't know how i missed that , many thanks @weePee